# Rails: Iterate over collection within a Model's Class Method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have a collection of `Foo` objects.  I want to create a class method that iterates over that collection and returns `true` if ALL objects in that collection have a certain value for an attribute.  Otherwise the class method returns `false`.

I attempted the following but it does not work:

```
class Foo < ActiveRecord::Base

  def self.all_have_number_value_999?
    each do |foo_object|
      return false if foo_object.number_val != 999
    end
    return true #all objects have #number_val == 999
  end

end
```

Now assume I got a collection of `Foo` objects somehow.  I will make up how I got the collection of Foo objects, but the importance is that `number_value_999?` can iterate over that collection.  In other words: some unknown scope generated the collection of `Foo` objects before hand.  I just want to iterate over that collection *within* a `Foo` class method.

```
Foo.where(id: [123, 456]).all_have_number_value_999?
```

It is complaining in the class method because it doesn't know how to iterate over the collection.  So that is my question: How do I iterate over a collection within a model's class method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reverse your logic and let the database do the work. If all of them have a `number_val` of `999` then none of them have a `number_val` that is **not** `999` and this is easily expressed:

```
def self.all_have_number_value_999
  !where.not(:number_val => 999).exists?
end
```

That will be a single fairly efficient database query.

Since this is a class method and class methods are mixed into relations (scopes are pretty much specific types of class methods after all), you can call this method on a relation and things like:

```
Foo.where(id: [123, 456]).all_have_number_value_999?
```

should work as would `Foo.all_have_number_value_999?`.

---

If you want to perform some arbitrary logic while iterating over the collection outside the database, then you could throw in an `all` call to resolve the query before iterating:

```
def self.all_have_number_value_999?
  all.each do |foo_object|
    ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Please see my updated question above.  I tried to be more descriptive.  You have a good answer here, but hopefully it is more clear what my question is now that I added more details.